# mockito matchers for Optional<String> and Map<String, String[]>

Tags: mockito, junit5

New to Junit, Please help me find mockito matchers for **Optional and Map<String, String[]>.**

```
public Model<SummaryModel> getAll(Map<String, String[]> queryParameters, Integer page,
            Integer limit, Optional<String> sort) throws PageNumberOutOfBoundsException;

when(service.getAll( any(), anyInt(),anyInt(), any())).thenReturn(mockedResource);
```

Answer (score 1):

We have different options, based on our requirement we can use the same. Below is some example of `Optional` and `Map<String, String[]>`.

For `Map<String, String[]>`

1. You can create your actual map with values and then pass like `Mockito.eq(myMap)`;
2. You can use `Mockito.anyMap()`

For `Optional`

1. Mockito.eq(Optional.ofNullable(sort))
2. Mockito.any(Optional.class)

Comment: For the case of `Optional`, you can pass `eq(Optional.ofNullable(anyObject()))`. Where both `eq` and `anyObject` have to be statically imported from `org.mockito.Matchers`.